# Array as argument for ant matchers in spring boot kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

In spring boot when using java its posible to pass array of strings as an argument to antMatchers

```
 private static final String[] LINK_PBL = {
            "/webjars/**",
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/images/**",
            "/",
            "/about/**",
            "/contact/**",
            "/error/**/*"

    };

.antMatchers(LINK_PBL)
```

above example works in java, bottom one does not work in kotlin.

```
  private val LINK_PBL = arrayOf(
            "/webjars/**",
            "/css/**",
            "/js/**",
            "/index",
            "/images/**",
            "/",
            "/about/**",
            "/contact/**",
            "/error/**/*"

    )
antMatchers(LINK_PBL)
```

It shows an error that noone of the functions can be called for given argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be passed using the [spread operator](https://riptutorial.com/kotlin/example/20551/spread-operator--passing-arrays-into-vararg-functions) — `*`:

```
antMatchers(*LINK_PBL)
```

This function uses the `vararg` keyword to define variable number of arguments. Kotlin makes a clear distinction between arrays and variable arguments. I assume it is done in order to prevent erroneous invocations.